# How to do Ansible conditional include_vars?

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to use `include_vars` based on `when` condition as follows:

```
- include_vars: clouderamanager.yml
  when: '{{ inventory_hostname }}' in groups['hadoop-clouderamanager']

- include_vars: hadoop-namenode.yml
  when: '{{ inventory_hostname }}' in groups['hadoop-namenode']

- include_vars: resourcemanager.yml
  when: '{{ inventory_hostname }}' in groups['hadoop-resourcemanager']

- include_vars: spark-history-server.yml
  when: '{{ inventory_hostname }}' in groups['spark-history-server']
```

I am getting `ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.`

```
The error appears to have been in '~/ansible/roles/hadoop-master/tasks/main.yml': line 4, column 36, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- include_vars: clouderamanager.yml
  when: '{{ inventory_hostname }}' in groups['hadoop-clouderamanager']
                                   ^ here
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing when condition following worked

```
when: inventory_hostname in groups['hadoop-clouderamanager']
```

Answer (score 0):

Add example for regular var.

```
- name: including vars called secrets
  include_vars: "vars.yml"

- name: including vars called secrets
  include_vars: "another_var_file.yml"
  when: "<variable name inside vars.yml> == '<value>'"
```